# How to check if the substring exists in a list of values in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of values which are of different types and I would like to check if a substring exists in the given list and when found, I want to get back the index of it.

I tried doing it with `any()` but it throws me an error saying `in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`. I am assuming, all the values in the list needs to be string in order to use `any()`. 
What other way I could use to achieve this?

Here is my Current code:

```
list_val = [1,18.0, 'printer', 'EXTRACT (123)']
string_val = 'EXTRACT'
any(x in string_val for x in list_val)
```

I even tried converting all the non-strings into strings and then wanted to use the above `any()` logic, but that was giving me other errors. I tried the following:

```
for i, val in enumerate(list_val):
    if not isinstance(val, str):
        list_val[i] = str(val)
```

This throws me the error: `isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`

Comment: You'd use `string_val in x`, to begin with.

Comment: based on your error message, I presume you overwrote the `str` type. Try `print(str)` to check. If the output is **not** `<type 'str'>`, that's a problem.

Comment: Your second exception indicates you have masked the built-in type by binding something else to the name `str`. Get rid of it with `del str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just filter your list on strings and only test against those that pass the filter:

```
any(string_val in item for item in list_val if isinstance(item, str))
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_val = [1,18.0, 'printer', 'EXTRACT (123)']
>>> string_val = 'EXTRACT'
>>> any(string_val in item for item in list_val if isinstance(item, str))
True
```

Note that I used `string_val in item`, not `item in string_val`; your example list makes it clear you want to see if there are any elements that contain `EXTRACT`, not if there are elements that are a substring of `EXTRACT` (e.g. `'EXT'`, `'RACT'`, etc.).

Your second attempt only failed because you appear to have assigned something else to the name `str`, because the `isinstance()` call is otherwise correct:

```
>>> isinstance("foo", str)
True
>>> str = "spam"
>>> isinstance("foo", str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
>>> del str
>>> isinstance("foo", str)
True
```

The problem is trivially fixed by removing the `str` binding again, as I did above You'll have to anyway, as you'll see the same exception using `any()` with an `isinstance()` filter.

Not that you need to alter `list_val` at all for `any()` to work, however.

Comment: Your answer still gives me the following `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-752296da52ed> in <module>
----> 1 any(string_val in item for item in list_val if isinstance(item, str))

<ipython-input-42-752296da52ed> in <genexpr>(.0)
----> 1 any(string_val in item for item in list_val if isinstance(item, str))

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`

Comment: @Tums: yes, because you still have rebound `str`. Remove that. `str` is not resolving to the built-in type but to something *else*.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was using Jupyter and I deleted that cell and I didn't realize it was still in the namespace.

Comment: How can I tweak the above code to make it work with a list of string values something like this: `string_val = ['EXTRACT', 'SUBTRACT', 'DEDUCT', 'ADDIT', 'CLEAR']`. That is I want to check if any of these strings exists in the given `list_val`. I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: @Tums either nest another `any()` loop inside (`any(v in item for v in string_val) for item in list_val)`) or use a regex instead (`any(re.search(r’(EXTRACT|SUBTRACT|DEDUCT|ADDIT|CLEAR)', item) for item in list_val)`.